# Invalid Application of sizeof to complete struct wordcounter

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, sizeof

I am writing a program that counts the number of times a word occurs in a text file. This is done through the use of a struct that contains the word and the count of that word. I am getting a compilation I am getting an error that reads:

> "Invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type struct wordcounter."

Any input on how to fix this problem and about my code in general is appreciated. I am new to c so I am open to advice unrelated to this question as well. Thanks a lot. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXWORDS 5000
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define MAXWORDLEN 100


int count = 0;
struct wordcount *wordPtr[MAXWORDS];

typedef struct wordcount *wordcountptr;

typedef struct wordcount {
    char word[50];
    int count;
} wordcount;


main()
{

    int wordfound = 0;
    int len;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int printcount;

    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE, stdin))> 0)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for( ; i<len; i++)
        {
            if(line[i] != isalnum(line[i]) && line[i] != 32)
                line[i] = 32;
            else
                line[i] = tolower(line[i]);
        }

        for( ; j<len; j++)
        {

            char currentword[MAXWORDLEN];

            if(line[j] != 32)
            {
                for(i=0; line[j] != 32; i++)
                    currentword[i] = line[j];
            }
            if(line[j] == 32)
            {
                for(i=0;i<MAXWORDS; i++)
                {
                    if(strcmp(currentword, (*wordPtr[i]).word) == 0)
                    {
                        (*wordPtr[i]).count++;
                        wordfound = 1;
                    }
                }

                if(wordfound == 0)
                {
                    wordPtr[i] = (struct wordcounter*)malloc(sizeof(struct wordcounter));
                    strcpy((*wordPtr[i]).word, currentword);
                    (*wordPtr[i]).count = 1;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            wordfound = 0;
        }
    }

    for(printcount = 0; printcount < count; printcount++)
        printf("There are %d occurances of the word %s\n", (*wordPtr[printcount]).count, (*wordPtr[printcount]).word);

    for(printcount = 0; printcount < MAXWORDS; printcount++)
    {
        free((void*)wordPtr[printcount]);
        wordPtr[printcount]= NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `wordcount` != `wordcounter` . Check your decl name vs the name you used in-code. There's more than one, btw.

Comment: Am I implementing getline incorrectly? I am getting a warning about my arguments. Also now I am getting a runtime error: Segmentation fault(core dumped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typedef struct wordcount {
    char word[50];
    int count;
} wordcount_t;//modify like this

wordPtr[i] = (wordcount_t*)malloc(sizeof(wordcount_t));//modify like this
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. So the issue had something to do with not having defined the an instance of the struct?

Comment: I am now getting a runtime error: segmentation fault (core dumped). I understand this had to do with trying to access memory that has not been allocated. Am I using getline correctly? I am getting warnings about it and wonder if it is causing this.

Comment: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`this is `getline` prototype,The first argument is `char **`,not `char *`,
you can use like this:`getline(&line, MAXLINE, stdin)`

Comment: Ok. I guess I am confused because I thought that when you refer to an array in c, it is a pointer to the first element of the array. Why would I need to specify the address of the line? I guess I am confused what char ** is vs char *. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: you can `man getline` on linux,if the first agument is `NULL`,the `getline` will allocate memory itself,so `getline` must know the address of `line` to make it point to memory it allocate.